# Why could I be getting far slower upload on wired connection to my router than WiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet

I recently changed ISP for ADSL. On my Mac, plugged directly into the router/model I get 30/1 Mbps up/down, both with the old ISP and the new one.
I thought that was just the way it is until I happened to test on my phone and got 20/7. Precise downloading speed varies depending on WiFi signal but I get 6-7Mbps up regardless - 7X faster than on my hard-wired Mac!

Some more details:

1. I was previously using a decent ADSL modem/router but have temporarily swapped to using the ISP-supplied device. So both routers are giving the same result in terms of upload performance.
2. My ethernet cabling was put in only very recently using cat6e and a 10-port powered switch which is plugged into one port on the ADSL modem. Only one device is actually using the ethernet at a time, it was set up for future expansion and to provide cabled networking to my home office.
3. I have noticed whenever I do a speedcheck on my Mac, the upload reads 0 for the first few seconds. I wonder if this could be some sort of clue.

[image]
[image]

4. My modem reports its connection: Downstream: 35.94 Mbps
   Upstream:   7.333 Mbps
5. My wiFi devices are not on the modem's own WiFi, but a mesh WiFi system which is also plugged into an ethernet socket on the modem. The modem's internal WiFi is turned off.

What could be causing the strange behaviour (great download, slow upload) on my wired connection relative to WiFi devices?

Comment: I'd try an "internal" speed test on your wired connection to another system at home.  Might be a an issue with the cabling where you might be getting a number of errors.

Comment: Could try testing the wiring itself, using different hardware &/or a program like iperf - some routers can even run iperf as a client/server themselves. And it's not entirely clear what's connected to what, where the connection's going when wired & on wifi. At any rate, a problem with the ISP's hardware like this warrants a call & "free" tech support (you're already paying for) by the ISP

Comment: @Hogstrom does cat6e _have_ separate up/down wires that could allow a cable to be faster in one direction than the other? I guess to run diagnostics I need two laptops running some test software, and plug them into different sockets to see where things get weird. Given my cabling is Gigabit only getting 1Mbps suggests a huge issue right - 1000X slower than it should support?

Comment: @Xen2050 as I said the issue was the same with a 3rd-partly ADSL modem before I switched to the ISP's hardware (I plan to switch back but wanted to be sure the ADSL was working first with minimal setup)

Comment: Yes, Gb ethernet should be full duplex (send/receive) at the same time.  If you can test from one system to another locally and you get the throughput then you know it could be the ADSL issue.

Comment: Easy way to eliminate whatever house network wiring you're using is to just plug a new short wire from a laptop directly into the router (or is it a modem/router combo?). And definitely do iperf for local network testing

Comment: The problem might be with the Ethernet network adapter on the computer.

Comment: Need to eliminate the cable as a source as @ xen2050 mentions, but also try a different Lan port on the router, or look in the documentation to see if you are plugged into a special "uplink" port